# Multiple sourcefolders and jars per project - maven vs gradle

Tags: maven, jar, gradle

I need to investigate if Maven and Gradle offers the same flexibility to generate multiple jar files per project for multiple source folders.

I know this is generally not recommended but I need to compare the functionality/flexibility of the two build tools when it comes to this requirement (a multi-module maven project structure is currently not an option).

**Gradle**

In gradle this is very simple:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src'
    }
  }
  other {
    java {
      srcDir 'other'
    }
  }
}
task otherJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.other.output
    classifier = 'other'
    customName = 'other.jar'
}
```

When building this with gradle the classfiles are organized like this:

```
build
 > classes
     > main
       > com
     > other
       > com
```

This is very nice since its possible to "backtrack" which source folders the corresponding classes originate from. As a result its possible to have identical package names for each sourceSet and still get separate jar files with the correct classes.

**Maven**

In maven this does not seem to be possible. Even though its possible to use a combination of the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) (for specifying multiple source folders) and the [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html) (for building multiple jar files) its only possible to split the sources on the package level, see [exclude, include](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/) in the [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html).

As I understand this comes from the fact that compiled classes are not organized in the **target/classes** folder based on their originating sourcefolders in maven.

So if one needs to:

1. Have multiple source folders for a project with possible identically named packages between the source folders.
2. Generate a jarfile for each sourcefolder.

one needs to go with gradle (or any other build tool that provides this flexibility). Or have I missed some secret backdoor in maven that offers the same flexibility?

Comment: The answer to this in Maven: Use a maven multi-module build which contains the different sources folders with their appropriate parts and which results in builds different jar file. Furthermore in Maven you can configure the javac via compiler arguments (-d) to define the default output location which is by default target/classes or target/test-classes which needs to changed.

Comment: Yes I know that the right approach is to use multi-module maven projects but that is currently not an option. How would you go about specifying a separate javac -d option for each source folder within a single project?

Comment: This is simply a useless discussion. If you already know to do it the correct way with a multi-module build than you should simply do it. If you say it's not option the result is simple keep your fingers away from maven. On the other hand you can define appropriate compiler arguments and define different locations for each execution of the maven-compiler-plugin. But you are starting to fight against Maven and one thing i can promise you: You will loose the combat.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this in Gradle, it fairly easy, do you require different dependencies for the artifacts you publish, or the same?

Comment: There is a reason why Maven discourages this. It is simply not a good practice to separate out jars in this manner.